# TypeError: this.props.postRecipes is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue identifying where to correct this issue. Long story short I put together a fetch "post" action/function to send form data to my backend. After making a few correction to syntax I keep getting this "TypeError: this.props.postRecipes is not a function" error. I am using Redux with react by the way.

Here is where its pointing to:

```
componentDidMount(){
        
        this.props.postRecipes()
        
    }
```

I had to import from my action directory I made in my file tree where I made my postRecipe() function at.

```
export const postRecipes=()=>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`
    
    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        // body:JSON.stringify(recipes),
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
     }
    }
    return(dispatch)=>{
        
    fetch(RECIPES_URL,config)
    .then(response => 
    response.json())
    .then(resp => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'Add_Recipe',
            payload:{
                name: resp.name,
                ingredients: resp.ingredients,
                chef_name: resp.chef_name,
                origin: resp.origin,
                catagoryId: resp.catagoryId 
            }
        })
    })
      .catch((error) => console.log.error(error))

    }
    
    
}
```

Here is my container component where I placed my lifecycle method at that is the focus of this issue

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import RecipeList from '../components/RecipeList'
import RecipeInput from '../components/RecipeInput'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { postRecipes } from '../actions/fetchRecipes.js'

class RecipeContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    
    componentDidMount(){
        
        this.props.postRecipes()
        
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <RecipeInput addRecipe={this.props.addRecipe} /> 
               <RecipeList recipes={this.props.recipes} deleteRecipe={this.props.deleteRecipe} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return{
    addRecipe: () => dispatch(postRecipes()),
    // deleteRecipe: id => dispatch({type: 'Delete_Recipe', id})
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeContainer)
```

Is anyone able to identify where it might be producing my error? I am betting that "this.props" in
this.props.postRecipes() is coming up undefined after I console logged it.

Comment: You're not actually assigning `postRecipes` anywhere to props.  Is that `addRecipe` supposed to be `postRecipes`?

Comment: Actually looks llike `mapStateToProps` is at fault.  Try adding a `postRecipes` function there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return{
    addRecipe: () => dispatch(postRecipes()),
    // deleteRecipe: id => dispatch({type: 'Delete_Recipe', id})
    }
}
```

to this

```
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return {
       postRecipes: () => dispatch(postRecipes()),  
    }

}
```